# How can STEGR (symmetric teleparallel gravity) have no curvature, no torsion and be 'nonmetric'?

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, differential-geometry, field-theory, curvature

I know that the [Symmetric Teleparallel Equivalent-to-General-Relativity](https://www.google.com/search?as_q=symmetric+teleparallel+general+relativity) (STEGR) theory is very new, and probably above my pay grade, but how can it not involve curvature, torsion OR a metric tensor?

Perhaps I don't fully grasp the concept of 'nonmetricity', a.k.a. $Q$, a.k.a. the 'covariant derivative' of a tensor....

Comment: Doesn’t It involve all of them? The connection it uses is related to the Levi-Civita connection ..

Comment: Can you give a reference? The first thing that pop after a search says that STEGR has a matric and a connection, which is not a metric connection. The curvature and torsion are zero.

Answer (score 0):

In STEGR there necessarily must be a metric tensor $g$. The geometry is equip with a connection $\Gamma$ that has vanishing total curvature, vanishing torsion, but non-vanishing nonmetricity $Q_{abc} = \nabla_{a}g_{bc}$. (Sometimes this will be
phrased as the connection *not being metric*, which may be where the confusion comes from).

Just like curvature can be related to a vectors rotation when parallel transported around a closed curve, [nonmetricity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nonmetricity_tensor) can be related to the change in lengths of vectors when parallel transported.

The most comprehensive reference on this sort of thing is probably [Hehl's 1995 paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9402012), but you can google for metric-affine gravity to find more introductory sources.